# How do I separate out unique rows in a list that has both a datetime and float column?

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, unique

I'm relatively new to Python, and I am having trouble separating out unique rows from a data set that I had recently converted into lists. I broke separated out the data's unixtime recordings and converted them into datetime. Then when I recombined the data into a list I tried to separate out the unique rows of data. But instead I get the error.

```
[[[datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 20, 0, 0) -16.0]
  [datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 20, 0, 0) -16.0]........
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "C:\Users\lenovo\Favorites\Microsoft 网站\Downloads\OTdataparser.py", line 33, in <module>
    indicies = np.unique(okdat, return_index = True) #<-- NOT WORKING
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\arraysetops.py", line 180, in unique
    perm = ar.argsort(kind='mergesort')
TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to float
```

My script is below.

```
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math


ds5 = np.genfromtxt("gpsdata.dat.140620", delimiter = '',
                    usecols = (2,4,5), dtype = object)

print ds5

ds = np.array([x for x in ds5 if x[0] == "06/20/2014"])
dot = ds[:,2].astype(float)

print ds

rndsht = np.genfromtxt(ds[:,1], delimiter = ".", dtype = float) #Rm decimal
print rndsht


dutc = np.array([datetime.utcfromtimestamp(x) for x in rndsht[:,0]])

print dutc
#dutc = np.array([datetime.utcfromtimestamp(x) for x in ds[:,1].astype(float)])

okdat = np.dstack((dutc,dot))
#okdat.astype(object)

print okdat

#indicies = np.unique(dutc, return_index=True) #<-- WORKS! BUT okdat??
#print indicies
indicies = np.unique(okdat, return_index = True) #<-- NOT WORKING 
print indicies

#Can't figure out how to use indicies to limit dot
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own unique function.

Here is quick example (you can probably do better). Note that is doesn't preserve order, but you could use insert and do that.

def

```
def unique(data):
    x = 0

    while x < len(data):
        i = data[x]

        c = 0

        while (i in data):
            c += 1

            data.remove(i)
        data.append(i)

        if (c <= 1):
            x += 1
    return data
```